# How to Configure Eclipse to use rospy library?

Tags: rospy, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to program ros programs in python using Eclipse. But, when I write " import rospy" in eclipse it gives an error. How to import rospy library in eclipse?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191128/how-to-configure-eclipse-to-use-rospy-library?/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can find the answer to your question [here](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Eclipse).

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0